# Having problem while trying to access the idp url after using saml plugin in grails for SSO

Tags: grails, single-sign-on, saml, grails-plugin, spring-security-saml2

I have installed a SAML plugin in Grails in my local project. I am able to see a page created from the plugin where I can click a button to go the IDP selection page. But when I am trying to go to the IDP selection page it is not working, a blank white screen is coming up and the URL to which the IDP page is redirected, I guess does not exist in the plugin.

Can someone please help me out in this? I am trying this for many days to understand how SAML will work but did not get any breakthrough.

[Whne i isntall the plugin after thqt the idp selection option is coming.Please check the screenshot as reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UaO7w.png)

[But after clicking on idp selection option blank page is coming.screenshot given for reference.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oajlz.png)

Comment: Please provide a minimal failing example, that shows the problem and all the relevant informations (e.g. missing urls from browser devtools, server logs with errors, ...)

Comment: Hi @cfrick. Thanks for your response.I have added some screenshots for your reference.Please let me know if you have any queries or you need any more details.